# How to solve Error in query (1442) MySql

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to insert some records to a table and update its auto incriment id in another table;

I have a trigger

```
delimiter #

create trigger test AFTER INSERT ON samples_track for each row begin
update sample_details set sampletrack_id = new.sampletrack_id where sample_details.sample_id = new.sample_id; end#

delimiter ;
```

And I am running a query

```
    INSERT INTO samples_track(sample_name,customer_id,contact_name,added_by,added_date,status,sample_id)
SELECT sample_name,
       customer_id,
       clinician_id,
       999,
       '2016-01-23',
       1,
       sample_id
FROM sample_details
WHERE sampletrack_id IS NULL;
```

The result is as below

> Error in query (1442): Can't update table 'sample_details' in stored
>   function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked
>   this stored function/trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the reason of this error is that when you insert a record mysql locks the table. you can't insert/update/delete rows of the same table where you insert.. because then the trigger would called again and again.. ending up in a recursion.

To solve your problem, have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25308588/mysql-error-cant-update-table-in-stored-function-trigger). Also, in [this forum](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,122354,201300#msg-201300) they suggest to use a before insert trigger... Worth a try.

Comment: it is a drawback of mysql. I'm also experienced the same issue