# MySQL error in trigger syntax

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger to allow only one line per table.
This database will be used by more than one software so I would like this automation to be done by the database.

Before the insert, the database should clean the previous register, plus the foreign tables.

At the moment I'm trying to clean the current table, but I'm having syntax errors

[image]

**EDIT:**

Adding a semicolon on `DELETE FROM sensor;`
[image]

Comment: Add semicolon after `DELETE FROM sensor`

Comment: I've tried it, I'm updating the OP..

Comment: I'm fairly certain you are not allowed by MySQL to modify the contents of the table the trigger is on.

Comment: I also tried this `CREATE TRIGGER TestDatabase.Sensor_AFTER_INSERT AFTER INSERT ON Sensor 
FOR EACH ROW DELETE FROM sensor WHERE idSensor != NEW.id;` and gave me this error *`TRIGGER command denied to user 'root'@'192.168.2.182' for table 'sensor'`* so I think you are correct..

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the begin/end:

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_sensor BEFORE INSERT ON `sensor`
FOR EACH ROW
DELETE FROM sensor;
```

You might encounter issues trying to delete during the insert, though.

Comment: Well the error is different now, possibly related to your last statement..
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25308588/mysql-error-cant-update-table-in-stored-function-trigger